Add additional menu for Ubuntu installation
I am aware of autoinstalll which gives the ability to customize Ubuntu installation.
I'm trying to see if there's a way to add additional menu for Ubuntu installation. I cannot find that in autoinstall.
For example, a menu that asks for X. Then the user enter the value he wants.
Then on installation, I can fetch and use the value of X when running my script from the late-commands section of autoinstall.
Is it possible?
